# Installing RPy2 for MacOS: add the directory of the R interpreter to the PATH environment variable

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, environment-variables, rpy2

I am trying to install RPY2 on my MacBook Air, Yosemite, and I've pretty much followed the instructions from the following [website](http://www.jamesstroud.com/jamess-miscellaneous-how-tos/python/installing-rpy2-on-os-x-python-2.x). More specifically, I:

- Installed R 3.3.2
- installed Rpy2 using `pip install rpy2`, as suggested by the RPY2 website
- Set the R_HOME variable to the R home directory with
  `echo 'R_HOME="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources"; export R_HOME' >> ~/.bashrc`

However, when I test whether this works in Python with
`from rpy2.rinterface import R_VERSION_BUILD`
I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface import R_VERSION_BUILD
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    """)
RuntimeError: The R home directory could not be determined.

    Try to install R <https://www.r-project.org/>,
    set the R_HOME environment variable to the R home directory, or
    add the directory of the R interpreter to the PATH environment variable.
```

**Do I indeed need to `add the directory of the R interpreter to the PATH environment variable` and, if so, how would I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

After you modify your `~/.bashrc` you'll probably have to run the following command
`source ~/.bashrc`
Otherwise, one adds R to the PATH like this:

```
export PATH=/directory/where/the/R/executable/is:${PATH}
```

Finally, I would not advise one to use the system's Python (unless in a throwaway setting such a container). Consider using `homebrew`, and install Python and R with it.

Comment: Hi @lgautier, thank you for your suggestion. I will test it immediately. Regarding downloading Python, I downloaded it from www.python.org itself. Is that also okay?

Comment: That's fine, I think (Mac owners can hopefully confirm). Important part is that it is recommended to leave the system's Python alone.

Comment: I have tried it in three ways (pointing to three different R executables), but still no luck. I get the same error even after rebooting the computer. I've checked that the PATH is set after reboot. Do you perhaps have any other suggestions?

Comment: When you open terminal, does the command "R RHOME" return a path ? This is basically what rpy2 is doing to fetch R's home. Also, probably a good idea to unset the environment variable `R_HOME` if R is in the PATH.